# What is the seed value when doing an unfunded transfer using the solana cli

Tags: pda, send-transaction

I am trying to recreate the transfer sol --allow-unfunded-recipient in other sdks. But confused on how this works
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b8b3d723da8b2d35b948c5e0abb4c37d6d862710/cli/src/wallet.rs#L703. What is the seed used when transferring to an unfunded account?
I know the address I want to transfer to, its just not funded until I transfer to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it quickly, just don't worry about seeds at all and transfer to the address.

They are used for `TransferWithSeed`, which is a pre-cursor to program-derived addresses. The concept is that with your pubkey, you can prove the derivation to some other address with some seed, and get control over the account at that pubkey.  So when you provide a `derived_address_seed` and `derived_program_id`, you can use `TransferWithSeed`.

Very important note: these are not program-derived addresses! If you're working with PDAs, don't use any of the `*WithSeed` instructions.